How do I use composite primary keys in r2dbcEntity and r2dbcRepository
My mysql table uses two fields as composite primary keys. In SpringBoot, I want to use r2dbcRepository.findById() to query data by composite primary keys. How do I define Entity and Repository?
I tried the annotations in jakarta.persistence, but queries that work in JPA don't work in r2dbc, and you can see from the sql log that the clause after where has only one field instead of two
